# Join touched lines with point layer in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, line, sql, st-touches

I have a road layer and point layer. How can I merge touching lines into one line where the lines intersects the points (delete pseudo nodes)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ST_LineMerge()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) on the entire road dataset (the points are not required):

```sql
WITH data(geom) AS (VALUES
('LINESTRING (10 10, 30 30)'),
('LINESTRING (70 40, 70 60)'),
('LINESTRING (40 60, 50 80)'),
('LINESTRING (40 60, 70 40)'),
('LINESTRING (30 30, 20 50, 40 60)'),
('LINESTRING (30 30, 50 20)'),
('LINESTRING (70 40, 50 20)')
)

SELECT (ST_Dump( ST_LineMerge( ST_Collect(geom) ) )).geom FROM data;
```

Obviously the attribution on the individual lines is not preserved.  But the points could be used to delete the original roads intersecting them, so that the merged roads can be added without duplication.